# How Do I Make a Dropdown Menu That Places A Text In a text Field

Tags: java, javascript, drop-down-menu

How do i make a drop down menu that when an option is chosen it creates a text that is placed in a text box. For Example,
Dropdown menu option1 = "are good"

i want the output to be, "Waffles Are Good". Waffles Will Automatically be there and they select an option from the drop down menu and it places the text "Are Good" Onto A Text Field

Comment: post what you have done till now.

Comment: do you want the code?

Comment: yes and can it be done in java instead of html, also can you place where the text goes inside a box

Comment: Are you asking about Java or Javascript? These are two completely different languages.

Comment: oops radiodef didnt relize i had js selected, but java, and the other answers for js helped me with something else

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Waffles <span id="whatarewaffles"></span></p>
<p>
    <label>What's with the waffles? 
        <select id="wafflemachine">
            <option value="are good">they are good</option>
            <option value="are delicious">they are delicious</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("wafflemachine").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("whatarewaffles").innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
};
</script>
```

You mean something like this?

Comment: yes but can it be done in java instead of html, also can you place where the text goes inside a box

Comment: but this is exactly what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1og0njhq/1/). Let me know is it helpful for you.

HTML

```
<select id="data1">
  <option value="good">good</option>
  <option value="too good">too good</option>
  </select>
<input type="text" id="data2" value="Waffles good"/>
```

Jquery

```
$("#data1").val("good").change(function(){
var k=($("#data1").find(":selected").text());
    $("#data2").val('Waffles'+k);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use jquery to do this.

You can check my full code here https://jsfiddle.net/tmhnfL9d/

```js
$('#selectme').change(function(){
  $("#sentence").html('Waffles');
  answer = $(this).val();
  $("#sentence").append(answer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectme">
  <option value= "">Please Select</option>
  <option value= " are Good">are Good</option>
  <option value= " are Bad">are Bad</option>
</select>
<p id="sentence">Waffles</p>
```

Comment: i might use this is there a way i can pm you?

Comment: You can ask me here bro.

Comment: or you can email me at kenneth@2m2kcreatives.com